# snapshotting rxgraph

Tags: ros, rxgraph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since I believe there must have been discussion about this topic already but haven't found sound solution/workaround so far, now I ask.

What would be better way to preserve `rxgraph` output than just taking screenshot image file, when the graph gets large? My concern is as follows but not limiting to them:

- All nodes appear in a file?
- Name of nodes legible?
- Topic name along with the connection b/w nodes legible?

What I do always is not the best at all. Take a screenshot of the whole graph and magnify on image viewers (for sharing purpose I use picasaweb often). Apparently I need better solution. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12426/snapshotting-rxgraph/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-12-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use the -o option to have it dump to a dot file and then you can render it afterwords using your preferred dot renderer such as graphviz.

I don't know the specific timing of the writing of the dot file, I would expect it to do so immediately after receiving the graph description from the master.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2011-12-23**:
I have used the dot file output before. If you save it in .svg format then you can create a .png with arbitrarily high resolution (up to a reasonable amount) so that everything is legible.